Is this variant of min-cut PTIME?
I am interested in the following variant of the min-cut problem. We are given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with $E\subseteq V\times V$, a penalty function $\rho:V\to \mathbb{N}$, and a source $s\in V$ and target $t\in V$. A cut is a subset $C \subseteq E$ such that there is no directed path from $s$ to $t$ in $G\setminus C$ (the graph obtained from $G$ simply by removing the edges of $C$). I define the cost of a cut $C$, written $c(C)$, to be
the number of edges in $C$ plus the penalty $\rho(v)$ of all nodes $v$ for which some incoming edge is not in $C$. Formally, $c(C) = |C| + \sum_{\substack{v\in V \text{ s.t.}\\\exists v' \in V \text{ with } (v',v)\notin C}} \rho(v)$. In other words, this is the usual cost of a cut, but you also pay a penalty when you do not cut all incoming edges of a node.
Question: Has this variant already been studied? Is it PTIME?

If you are interested in the problem, let me point out that it is related to our recent preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2412.09411. In the vocabulary of the paper, the problem presented here subsumes the computation of the reliability of some queries left open by the paper, such as abcd|be.

I believe we can reduce this problem into standard weighted min-cut (and is thus in PTIME).
First, we notice that if $\rho(v) \geq |N^-(v)|$ for a vertex $v\in V$, i.e., it has a penalty higher than its in-degree, then it is always worth adding all incoming edges of $v$ into $C$. We thus assume that $\rho(v) < |N^-(v)|$ for all $v$. (This step might not be necessary.)
Now we split every vertex--i.e., replace every vertex $v\in V$ by two vertices $v^a$ and $v^b$ and replace every edge $(u,v)\in E$ by $(u^b,v^a)$; and for each $v\in V$ add $(v^a,v^b)$ into our new $E$.
Let us define the weight of $(v^a,v^b)$ as $(|N^-(v)| - \rho(v))$ for $v\in V$ and the weight of the rest of the edges as 1 (except $(v^s,v^s)$ and $(v^t,v^t)$ which are set to $\infty$).
Thus, if there is a solution $C'$ of the weighted min-cut instance with cost $\kappa$, then there is a solution $C$ for the original instance with cost $\kappa + \sum_{v\in V}\rho(v)$ and vice versa.

Hi, thanks for the answer but I don't understand the construction. Say you have 3 parallel paths of length 2 from $s$ to a vertex $v$, and one edge from $v$ to $t$, with $v$ having penalty value $\rho(v) = 3$ (equal to $|N^-(v)|$) and all other vertices having penalty 0. Then the optimal solution is to remove the 3 incoming edges of $v$, having cost 3 plus penalty 0. But in the weighted min-cut instance $C'$ that you build, the optimal solution has cost $\kappa = 1$, cutting the edge going out of $v^b$. I don't understand how this relates to the optimal solution of the original instance.

The node $v$ in your graph is represented in the new instance by an edge $(v^a,v^b)$ with weight $|N^-(v)| - \rho(v) = 0$. The optimal solution to this instance is to remove only this edge, and we obtain a total cost of $\kappa = 0$ (not 1, plus this $\kappa$ is equal to the optimal value of the original instance, minus $\sum_v \rho(v)$). I edited the answer slightly since some details might have been lost in the wording.
